# Trigger event after v-on fn

Tags: vuejs3

Let's say I have a component with v-on function on it eg. <Test @data="fn"> I want to be able to trigger action in "Test" component when "fn" from parent component finishes execution (assuming its async fn).

Comment: Could you create a *runnable* [mcve]? Show us the parent and the child components and explain what you're trying to achieve. Consider using Vue SFC Playground, codesandbox.io or similar if you need a node-like online environment.

Comment: Point here being, there are way too many possible cases to consider. Your question is too general. Answers to it are likely to be incomplete (not covering all cases). You're more likely to get a useful answer when you provide a concrete example and explain what you're trying to achieve, how you've attempted to achieve it and why you think what you attempted should work.

Comment: I needed to wait until fn passed on component finished to do its job and then do something in child component after "emit 'data'". I handled it by changing emit to get fn from useAttrs.